# How to change language in-game with I18NBundle in libGDX?

Tags: java, localization, libgdx

I've created a I18NBundle and some .properties files containing the strings. To create the bundle i wrote this:

```
baseFileHandle = Gdx.files.internal("Language/Lang");

da_DK = new Locale("da", "DK");
en_GB = new Locale("en", "GB");

Lang = I18NBundle.createBundle(baseFileHandle, en_GB);
```

This works perfectly well, and I can extract the values from the bundle to get my strings, and it also works by using da_DK instead of en_GB when i initialize the bundle.

My proplem is that I want to be able to change the language in game by pressing a button, but I have no idea how to do that.

I've googled the problem, but cant seem to find an answer.

I hope that you understood my problem, and that you can help me :)

Answer (score 7):

If you have a look at the code ([`I18NBundle.setLocale(...)`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/I18NBundle.java#L384), which is a private method) you will see this JavaDoc:

> Sets the bundle locale. This method is private because a bundle can't change the locale during its life.

That means, what you want to do is not possible. What you can do of course, is creating a new `I18NBundle` supplying another `Locale` to the constructor and basically just replacing the current one. In case you are using an `AssetManager` to load it, this is also possible, you would just need to unload it and then load it once more with different parameters.